# ZF2 Redis: how to set expiration time for a key

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework, redis, zend-framework2

I have to set up a Redis on a server to store information from Zend Framework 2.
For now, I can store information, but I can not to give them an expiration time for they naturally renew themselves after a while.

I have not found some documentations about this step and it seems to me rather obscure.

My code:

page: config/autoload/cache.global.php

```
return array(
    'caches' => array(
        'redis' => array (
            'adapter' => array (
                'name' => 'redis',
                'lifetime' => 60, //doesn't work
                'options' => array (
                    'server' => array (
                        'host' => 'x.x.x.x',
                        'port' => x
                    ),
                    'ttl' => 10, // seems to have no effect
                    'namespace' => 'mycache',
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

in Controller :

```
..
use Zend\Cache\StorageFactory;
..
        $redis = StorageFactory::factory ($this->getServiceLocator ()
             ->get ('config')['caches']['redis']);

        if ($redis->hasItem ('test')) {
                var_dump($redis->getItem ('test'));
                $redis->removeItem('test');
        } else {
            $redis->addItem('test', 'testtest');
        }
..
```

I tried several methods, but everytime, the result is the same, no expiration information appears in Redis :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get mycache:test
"testtest"
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl mycache:test
(integer) -1
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
$redis = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Cache\RedisFactory');
$redis->getOptions()->setTtl(10);
$redis->setItem('test', 'Custom Value');
```

So there is no need to set it globaly in factory. 
This work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my redis factory bellow:

```
 <?php
 namespace Application\Service\Factory;

 use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
 use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
 use Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\RedisOptions;
 use Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Redis;

 class RedisCacheFactory implements FactoryInterface
 {
     public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
        $config = $config['redis'];

        $options = new RedisOptions();
        $options->setServer(
            [
                'host' => $config["host"],
                'port' => $config["port"],
                'timeout' => $config["timeout"]
            ]
        );
        $options->setTtl(60);

        /**
         * This is not required, although it will allow to store anything that can be serialized by PHP in Redis
         */
        $options->setLibOptions(
            [
                \Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER => \Redis::SERIALIZER_PHP
            ]
         );

        $redis = new Redis($options);

        return $redis;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the example, the TTL is set to 60 seconds and its working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Predis\Client has a "magic call" method command executor for setEx:

```
$redis->setEx($key, $expireTTL, $value);
```

- This will set key if does not exist with passed value for a custom expiration time.
- This will update existing key, resetting expiration time.

Double check as you mentioned to see that everything works as expected:

127.0.0.1:6379>dump your_key
127.0.0.1:6379>ttl your_key

Hope it helps :) !

Answer (score -1):

```
return array(
    'caches' => array(
        'redis' => array (
            'adapter' => array (
                'name' => 'redis',
                'options' => array (
                    'server' => array (
                        'host' => 'x.x.x.x',
                        'port' => x
                    ),
                    'Ttl' => 10, // Starting with capital letter
                    'namespace' => 'mycache',
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```